# Why isn't my post method hitting the controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am just trying to send a simple model back to my controller to update an object. For some reason this is evading me.

Controller method:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = Enums.Roles.SiteAdmin)]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "BuildingId,Name")] Building building)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            service.Update(building);
            return Json(new { Status = "Success!" });
        }

        return Json(new { Status = "error." });
    }
```

EF model:

```
public class Building
{
    [Key()]
    public int BuildingId { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript post method:

```
    $('.saveOnBlur').on('blur', function (e) {
        var newBuildingName = $(this).prop("innerText");
        var editBuildingId = $(this).siblings('.hiddenId').children().first().val();

        var modifiedBuilding = { BuildingId: Number(editBuildingId), Name: newBuildingName };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Equipment/Buildings/Edit",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: { building: JSON.stringify(modifiedBuilding) }
        });
    })
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I am able to create objects using a very similar approach, but this code doesn't even hit the controller method, I just immediately get an internal error 500 (not 404). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the error message you get ?

Comment: @Dabbas from the console in the F12 tools: jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:55698/Equipment/Buildings/Edit 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Nothing else happens

Comment: I'm not sure how to see the actual error message?

Comment: You will have to debug. It could be `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`, if you do not provide a valid value it will stop before it even reaches your code. I do not see any javascript code that includes a value in the http header.

Comment: From Network tab are you using Firebug ?

Comment: I did have that error before with the token but I fixed that. That one actually directed to a real error page though instead of just saying "internal error" which is not very helpful

Comment: I'm just using the Chrome developer tools

Comment: @Igor: That's exactly what the issue is, I think. Nothing in the AJAX call includes a request verification token.

Comment: Is the controller for the edit function named Buildings (BuildingsController)?

Comment: Ohhh I bet you are right. I did add the token to the page but I am not sending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to debug. It could be `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`, if you do not provide a valid value it will stop before it even reaches your code. I do not see any javascript code that includes a value in the http header.

To trouble-shoot comment it out and see if it hits the method. If not try the next filter which is your authorization filter and see if that is causing your code not to be executed.

If you already have code to handle tokens sent over ajax great, if not there are a lot of previous questions with good answers on SO which describe how you can do it like by creating a modified `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` that reads it  from the http header.

---

Additional things to check.

1. change the data payload to `data: JSON.stringify(modifiedBuilding)`
2. check your route as well `/Equipment/Buildings/Edit`. You can provide the routing configuration in your question to make it easier.

Comment: Taking both of them out doesn't fix it. :/

Comment: @eddie_cat - change the data payload to `data: JSON.stringify(modifiedBuilding)`

Comment: @eddie_cat - and check your route as well `/Equipment/Buildings/Edit`. You can provide the routing configuration in your question to make it easier.

Comment: Wow. changing the data in the ajax request worked. Thanks so much, I could have spent all day trying to find that.

Answer (score 0):

I have suffered the same error a few times.

Generally, when you get a 500 error without even hitting a breakpoint at the start of your controller, something is failing before the request is routed to your controller.

Main suspects for that:

1 - Routing is misconfigured. So the 500 is happening because you don't have an appropriate route for the parameter

2 - Model is not accepting null data, so parsing of your data fails before it is passed to your controller

3 - A custom filter is failing